# Meteor - Selecting first two objects in a mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a signup list I am trying to build out, so people can signup, be rearranged, and deleted. Here is the problem I am having; I want to select the first two items (keys) from a MongoDb collection. How can I do this so the next two people in line are displayed in a new template. I know that find might be able to help, but I'm really unsure of what exactly I am searching for. is it easier to limit everything in the #each loop?

This is my code:

**Server Side:**

```
Meteor.publish( 'artists', function() {
  return Artists.find( {}, { sort: { order: 1 } } );
});
```

**Client Side:**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { Session } from 'meteor/session'


import './main.html';

var $ = require('jquery');
require('fancybox')($);

let initSortable = ( sortableClass ) => {
  let sortableList = $( sortableClass );
  sortableList.sortable( 'destroy' );
  sortableList.sortable();
  sortableList.sortable().off( 'sortupdate' );
  sortableList.sortable().on( 'sortupdate', () => {
    updateIndexes( '.sortable' );
  });
};

let updateIndexes = ( sortableClass ) => {
  let items = [];

  $( `${sortableClass} li` ).each( ( index, element ) => {
    items.push( { _id: $( element ).data( 'id' ), order: index + 1 } );
  });

  Meteor.call( 'updateArtistOrder', items, ( error ) => {
    if ( error ) {
      console.log( error.reason );
    }
  });
};

Template.artists.onCreated( () => {
  let template = Template.instance();

  template.subscribe( 'artists', () => {
    initSortable( '.sortable' );
  });

});

Template.artists.events({
  'submit #add-artist' ( event, template ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let artist = {
      artistName: template.find( '[name="artistName"]' ).value
    };

    Meteor.call( 'addArtist', artist, ( error ) => {
      if ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
      } else {
        $( event.target ).get(0).reset();
        $( '[name="artistName"]' ).focus();
        initSortable( '.sortable' );
      }
    });
  },

    'click .delete-artist' ( event, template ) {
    if ( confirm( 'Are you sure? This is permanent!' ) ) {
      Meteor.call( 'deleteArtist', this._id, ( error ) => {
        if ( error ) {
          console.log( error );
        } else {
          updateIndexes( '.sortable' );
        }
      });
    }
  }

});

Template.artists.helpers({
  artists() {
    return Artists.find();
  }
});
```

**Collection:**

```
Artists = new Mongo.Collection( 'artists' );

Artists.allow({
  insert() { return false; },
  update() { return false; },
  remove() { return false; }
});

Artists.deny({
  insert() { return true; },
  update() { return true; },
  remove() { return true; }
});
```

**Template:**

```
   <template name="artists">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="page-header">Next Up</h3>

    <ul class="list-group sortable">
      {{#each artists}}
        <li data-id="{{_id}}" class="list-group-item clearfix">
          <span class="pull-left">{{order}}. {{artistName}}</span>
          <i class="fa fa-remove pull-right text-danger delete-artist"></i>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <form id="add-artist">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
          <label for="artistName">Register Here:</label>
          <input type="text" name="artistName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
              </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add Name</button>
          </div>
        </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to implement this:

1. Sort the data from the publication in the client side and maintain a marker for the postion. Let says you have 10 documents, you can sort them out in an order and set the marker as 2(you can use `session` variable for this) and similarly for the next template as 4 and so on.
2. Use this [package](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/paginated-subscription). This package allows to you subscribe the publication with pagination. here you can limit the documents to 2 and accordingly use the functions mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/percolatestudio/paginated-subscription/) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in your client-side helper :

```
Template.artists.helpers({
  artists() {
    return Artists.find({}, { limit: 2, sort: {order: 1} });
  }
});
```

With that, only two objects will be retrieved from your mongodb collection.